# Unread count for emails matching Primary AND Inbox labels

Tags: gmail-api

With the Primary tab or Inbox by Gmail it's impossible get an accurate total of the unread count in the primary/personal category (ie. primary inbox). In particular when emails are Marked as Done without being read. The issue arises when emails are marked as done without being read, the inbox label is removed, but the unread count remains the same.

Solution:
This following existing API call to retrieve the unread count needs to be modified to accept "multiple" label ids.

ex. CATEGORY_PERSONAL + INBOX
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/CATEGORY_PERSONAL|INBOX

Comment: Just wondering if I'm understanding you correctly. Do you want to get the amount of messages that has "overlapping" labels?

Comment: Yes correct, the accurate "threadsUnread" or "messagesUnread" and not the "resultSizeEstimate" which I know is possible through the other API call https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages